# Vue dotenv variables not working in server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dotenv

We have a Vue project and the .env & .env.production variables work fine in local **npm run dev** and when pass to production whit **npm run build** but in our production and develop server this not works. What we can do?

Comment: not work in what way?

Comment: please provide more context

Comment: we are using forge to deploy; our server provider is digital ocean. and this problem happen when we launch to prod our application.